# My Sql DATE_SUB() and codeigniter Active records issue?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

i am using codeigniter active records to execute a simple mysql query to select data in last one hour.

so my query is:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE added_datetime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

and my codeigniter code to form this query is:

```
$data=array(
            'added_datetime >='=>'DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)',

            );
            $query=$this->db->get_where('tablename',$data);
```

now the issue is codeigniter adds a single quotes around the DATE_SUB function and due to this the query not works on mysql server.

codeigniter produces:

```
SELECT * FROM (`tablename`) WHERE `added_datetime` >= 'DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)'
```

i also tried by adding `FALSE` as 3rd parameter in `get_where` but stil not worked

```
$query=$this->db->get_where('tablename',$data,FALSE);
```

it also produced the same query as above.
So please suggest me how to solve this issue.

-Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try doing something like this instead:

```
$this->db->where("added_datetime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)", NULL, FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get('tablename');
```

`$this->db->get_where();` doesn't provide the function to unescaping your where clause.